# Require Dependency Only On Certain Method Call

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a library of functions that is packaged up as a gem. One of these functions requires the use of a third-party gem that itself has a long list of dependencies.

Is there a way that I can set up my gem so that users can install it and use those functions in the gem that don't have the third-party dependency without the runtime complaining?

I want an exception to be raised when the method with the dependency is called, but the user should be able to use the other functions without a runtime error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your functions to modules (maybe modules to files too) that are depending or not depending gem. including `GemDependent` module trying to require your gem if not then redefine all gem dependent functions to raise exception.

```
module YourFunctions
  module GemDependent

    def self.included(klass)
      require "yourgem"
    rescue LoadError
      instance_methods.each do |m|
        define_method(m) { raise "you need yourgem to run #{m}" }
      end
    end

    def gem_dependent_function
    end
  end

  include GemDependent

  def no_dependent_function
  end
end

include YourFunctions
gem_dependent_function
#  "you need yourgem to run gem_dependent_function"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know how to do this, have a look at the various wrapper libraries for http, json, yaml etc.

a good example is https://github.com/rubiii/httpi where you can configure one of 3 http adapters. the adapters themselves require the individual dependencies within ruby.

the problem is, that the end-user needs to somehow know how to install the 3rd party gems. it's currently not possible to implement optional dependencies within ruby gemspecs.